# Detect SYN flood attack in python

Tags: linux, tcp, ddos, socket

I have a piece of python code as follow

```
s = socket.socket()
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind((IP, PORT))
s.listen(256)
while True:
    revdata = ""
    try:
       c, addr = s.accept()
       t = threading.Thread(target=handletcp, args=(c,addr))
       t.start()
    except socket.error as exc:
        log("Error: " + str(exc))
s.close()
```

Currently, my server, which handles 64 IPs, usually gets SYN flood attack. The python service has maximum ~200 TCP connections normally. I want to detect SYN flood attack and suspend the service within python code. Any idea of how to do that efficiently?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

A SYN flood attack is not visible at the level of normal TCP sockets. `accept` only returns if the TCP handshake is done - which is exactly not the case with SYN floods.

Comment: thanks! Now I'm monitoring RAM/CPU usage inside the python code to know when I should stop the service. Is that good enough?

Comment: @dk1111: I'm not sure if your fundamental idea of suspending the service on SYN flood attacks is the right approach in the first place. Usually there are better ways like SYN cookies to deal with the attack. As for monitoring RAM/CPU - this might also cause your service to suspend itself for other reasons than just SYN floods.

Comment: yeah, I have some other failover servers and apparently the attackers don't have enough resources to attack all of my servers, so it's fine for suspending the service for a few hours. I've tried setting syncookies but it seems not helping the situation, I'm using ubuntu 18.04